# How to style NamePicker using themes?

Tags: xpages

How can I style NamePicker from extensions library using themes? I need to style it using Twitter Bootstrap, it means I need to assign 'btn' like class to all its buttons (add, ok, cancel etc.) and so on. I am able to assign class to common button on xpages using themes, but it doesnt influence buttons on NamePicker dialogue? Do they use some different theme id? How can I obtain it?

I have looked into Boostrap4Xpages project source but cant figure out the proper technique. Something can be adjusted by themes and assigning proper class attriutes, sometimes the custom renderers has to be involved. But I cant find a way how it is for NamePicker.

Comment: Does it work if you add a 'class' of 'btn' to the attrs under All Properties of the namepicker?

Comment: There is no attrs section for NamePicker

Comment: Themes, on their own, are going to be insufficient for this. Themes allow you to override component properties, but that only impacts the resulting HTML if the renderer looks at the properties you're overriding. So ultimately you would need an alternative renderer that uses an approach similar to what Bootstrap4XPages already does with other components.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry there is no way (As far as i know) to set theme ID's for the Dialog Picker's child elements (Button, TextAreas ..). The only way to Change there Style is to overwrite the css styleClasses wich are assigned to them. E.g xspPickerButton2 = search Button on the Dialog.

Here a short example what i mean:

```
<style>
    .xspPickerButton2 {
        background-color:red;
    }
</style>

<xp:inputText id="field"></xp:inputText>
<xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="field">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:dominoViewNamePicker viewName="_People"
            labelColumn="$17">
        </xe:dominoViewNamePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:namePicker>
```

This Code will create a NamePicker and a Field. If you open the namePicker the Background of the Buttons on the Dialog will be red. You can put the css in a file wich you can include in the resources of the Page. But there is no known way to add theme ids to child elements in XPages (There was a question with a bountie already on Stackoverflow but without any answer) wich would be needed for this.

Another way would be to create your own name Picker by extending the extlib control and add theme ID's to ist children.

Comment: Great answer.  I would just add/clarify that you would do what Micheal suggests by adding your own css file that is set to be loaded last. It will then overwrite any matching classes.   You could also do this with jQuery, but I think the above is your best solution.

Comment: I think David's problem will be that he want to add bootstrap classes to the namepicker elements - adding custom CSS does not solve this. 
David, I think your best bet is to add a scriptBlock which gets certain namepicker elements (for example, the buttons) with dojo.query() and add bootstrap classes to them with dojo.addClass().

Comment: Both way's aquire a lot of work: But i think a CSJS wich query's through the whole Dialog and tries to assign new classes to all items can hold much more Trouble (browser, missing ids, duplicate classes) then creating css files wich let the NamePickerDialog nearly look the same then a bootstrap Dialog. I have say that i dont have much experience with bootstrap but i already had to Change some Picker's style for different applications and both ways are tricky.

Comment: I know I can do it by using JS on-fly class replacement. But its also my lesson with themes and custom renderers in Xpages and I cant find any offical docs on renderers for more comples controls. I looked into Bootstrap4Xpages source but NamePicker renderer(BootstrapNamePickerRenderer) is empty, it only extends NamePickerRenderer from ExtLib and nothing else. So I have no idea how does it work ...